# Как реализовать фильтр DDOS атак?

Tags: ddos

В интернете сейчас много различных сервисов по защите от ддос атак. Вообще возник такой вопрос, как создать свой фильтр от ддос атак. Т.е я имею 2машини, 1машина та на которую будут обращаться пользователи, другая машина с каналом в 100мб, где соответственно будет все обрабатываться и отправляться обратно. На первой машине мне нужно провести фильтрацию всего трафика, а далее передать на обработчик. Расскажите, объясните.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

на первой настраиваете фильтрацию - подробно описание есть на хабре например тут [Простой и эффективный метод отразить http DDoS от 50мбит с помощью nginx и iptables](http://habrahabr.ru/post/84172/) - дублировать смысла не вижу.

От себя скажу так на сегодня многие зарубежные дц предлагают сервера в том числе и виртуальные с гигабитными каналами. правда в случае вдс это будет шаред канал но все же гигабитный. к чему это? - это к тому что на практике у меня сервак со 100мб досом справился вообще без фильтрации.

Comment: Мне нужно защитить от ддоса небольшой игровой сервер, всего 2 порта, остальные можно закрывать. Не подскажешь?